# How to add an excerpt and read more link to a page?

Tags: functions, pages, excerpt, read-more

I've a custom/static "homepage.php" in my templates directory at my WordPress. Now I need to show differents "page excerpts" in my homepage, but I don't know what should be do it.

At this moment I've in my "functions.php" de following function:

```
function excerpt_page() {
  add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
add_action('init', 'excerpt_page');
```

With this function, I've in my Page editor a new field available where I can put an summary of the page.

Somebody has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much!

Finally, I've succeeded with the following code :D

```
<?php
$pages = get_pages('include=10,20,30,40,50,60');
foreach ($pages as $page) {
  $featured_content = '<div class="four columns">'.
                        '<h4><a href="'. get_page_link($page->ID) .'" title="'. $page->post_title .'">'. $page->post_title .'</a></h4>' .
                        '<p>'. $page->post_excerpt .'</p>' .
                      '</div>';
  echo $featured_content;
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you looking for... To display excerpt of specific page, you can use this code:

```
<?php
    $post_id = 2; // substitute to your page id
    $my_post = get_post($post_id);
    echo "<p>$my_post->post_excerpt</p>";
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink( $post_id ).'">read more</a>';
?>
```